# Are there women only tournaments for lower rated players?

Tags: tournament

Are there women only tournaments for lower rated players? There are many for top women, but not for me.

I can't seem to find any, but it would be fun. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may depend on your location, but such tournaments do exist.

For example, the [2019 Texas Women's Chess Championship](http://www.uschess.org/assets/msa_joomla/XtblMain.php?201908186972) had some low-rated players. The [2019 Wisconsin Junior Open](http://www.uschess.org/msa/XtblMain.php?201911035872.4-12694989) had a females-only section, with any female juniors from Wisconsin eligible to play in it, regardless of rating.

Upcoming, the U.S. Women’s Open will be in June in Las Vegas, and seeing as how there are U1400 prizes, it clearly isn't just for elite players.

Answer (score 1):

There is not that much demand.  Tournaments are money making efforts for the sponsors.

If you want to play at a low level then just enter an open section limited to the rating you can play at.  Many tournaments have lower rated sections that go way down in ratings,  some only have two sections  and some may only have one due to small amount of people expected.

NOTE that your chances are bigger of finding one as the tournament size increases. Clearly the best would be at national tournaments followed by large regional ones.  Then large major cities and possibly may also some selected states.

USCF magazine should list all tournaments with the section ratings they offer.